# What are your mouse buttons programmed to?

Tags: mouse

If you have a multi-button mouse like me (I use a Kengsington Optical Elite and a Mighty-Mouse), what do you program each button to? There was a similar thread but I don't think I ever saw what each individual button was programmed for (keystroke macros).

Anyone care to share?

Thanks!

- Ryan

Comment: What key commands do you use?

Comment: @MtL I answered with them!

Answer (score 1):

I use a Contour Shuttle Pro 2.0 with Logic.

The inner wheel is for horizontal zoom.
The outer jog is for the playhead.

Buttons are:

- play/pause
- return playhead to last insert point
- play selected region
- loop selected region (add modifier for a non-quantized loop)
- turn loop on/off
- cmd
- ctrl
- shift
- tool tray
- mouse wheel is vertical scroll
- cmd + mouse wheel is horizontal scroll
- opt + mouse wheel is vertical zoom

-=-

I use the mouse right click for scissors.
Cmd + left click alternates between cross fade tool and velocity tool. Ctrl and right click is the regular right click context menu.

All this to say, I'm pretty useless navigating an arrangement in Logic without my Shuttle.

Comment: Cool. I bet you're super-fast. Aren't multi-button devices a lifesaver?

Comment: I love the Shuttle so much. I've started playing with Ableton lately, and I'm avoiding using the Shuttle to see if I can get speedy without it. (Which would make portable work much easier.) But it's so hard to crawl when I know how fast I am in Logic.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Kensington Expert mouse... left-up click: Exposé All Windows (very useful to go between Pro Tools and Soundminer all the time). And right-up Cmd+S :-)

Also working with Shift, Alt and Cmd + the integrated shuttle wheel is amazing.

Comment: Cool! Doesn't Kengsington have a feature to go straight to a specific program? That might be better than using the expose!

Comment: and +1 for Command+S. I accidentally press Command+S all the time when I'm using a PC in Microsoft Word because I press it so often in Pro Tools - haha

Comment: @Ryan yes, I use that too. Also ctrl+Tab for the right-up click is a very good option

Answer (score 1):

Moving to a trackball, I really  missed the 2D scroll wheel of the mighty mouse. So I set both top buttons to go into scroll mode with 3rd party software. But that doesn't work very well. I think I may steal Miguel's set up.

MWAHAHAHAHAHA

Answer (score 1):

I have a Kensington trackball, using pro tools I have the buttons set to the following:

Bottom left- Left Click
Top Left- selector tool
Top Right- grabber tool
Bottom Right- Trim tool
Top Chord- pencil
Bottom Chord- zoom tool

With this configuration you can edit much faster (of course for fades you will have to go to the selection tool and use D, F and G).

This is also the setup used at [Danetracks](http://www.danetracks.com/).  I just recently started editing and mixing like this and it works really well.

Comment: Cool - you don't like the smart-tool while editing?

Comment: I like it but it doesn't always work as I want it to without having to zoom in/ out, especially when adjusting fades.  It's nice to get exactly what I need, and it's almost instantaneous switching from tool to tool with a little practice.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Kensington Expert Mouse.  I have a bunch of different macros that I have written and can load depending on what I'm doing.

My default setup is just right click, left click, exposé and show and show desktop.  Those cover most of everything fine, and I just use keyboard quick keys to do what I do.

If I'm doing music, I have a few macros that come in handy.  I have one that can automatically do a replacement track for drums, or create a midi trigger track.  I have one that can remove the sibilance from a vocal track and move it to another track to be eq'd and compressed differently (makes a HUGE difference!).  Few others as well, but I don't remember them off the top of my head.

Comment: A de-essing key command! Brilliant.