# Pro Tools Keyboard Shortcuts Macro'd to a Gaming Keyboard

Tags: pro-tools, keyboard, shortcut

I use a [Razer Arctosa](http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169415000/parentCategoryID.35156900/categoryId.54626500) which I was thinking of selling, but later changed my mind after thinking of using the macro capabilities for PT. I'm fairly new to PT and not very familiar with a lot of the keyboard shortcuts, so I was wondering if you have a gaming keyboard or know some essential/over used shortcuts that could be macro'd to one button to work quicker without having to try to remember the shortcut (eg: Ctrl+Shift+I to F1), what would you use and what empty keys would macro them to?

Answer (score 1):

Try cross-referencing [this post](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/7223/favourite-pt-quick-key), [this post](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/how-are-your-quickeys-workflows), & [this post](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/2830/what-are-your-mouse-buttons-programmed-to).

Additionally, it doesn't hurt to learn the keyboard shortcuts as not every system you sit in front of will have macros pre-programmed. There should be a .pdf in your Digidesign > Documentation > Pro Tools folder that has all the shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I was thinking about the same thing as well but I thought I'd might as well make use of the macro features since I have them..

Comment: I certainly understanding trying to utilize all the tools that are at your disposal. It was merely a suggestion to not become too reliant on them if you are new to the software.

Answer (score 0):

I remember buying a custom gaming keypad for Pro Tools specifically to have more macro ability - and I don't even think I ever plugged it in and set it up at all. I think it's still in the factory box sitting in a drawer somewhere.

I use a mouse with 5 buttons instead - works like a charm for me. And I have QuicKeys - so I either bring my QuicKeys to another gig outside my studio but 90% of the time I work out of my own studio. And if someone changes my mouse settings I get real mean!

Comment: What do you use on your mouse? I've got a Razer Orochi and it can save macros and information onboard so if I plug it into another computer it will have the same setup even without the drivers and stuff.